# Disable Gesture Recognizers in a *subview* so that superview Gesture Recognizers can run

Tags: xcode, macos

I have an NSView (the canvas), into which I'm dropping a set of TextView subclasses (small boxes). The TextView classes have GestureRecognizers on them for drag drop (move) and select.

The canvas has two modes:

- drawing
- text

*In text mode*, I can interact with the TextView classes - I can click on them, edit etc.

*When I switch to drawing mode*, I want to disable the TextView boxes completely, and have all events/gestures be captured by the Canvas.

That way I can do Pan/Click events on the whole of the canvas, and the TextView boxes should be visible but otherwise ignored/disabled.

*To enter drawing mode* I disable the TextView boxes as follows (if the boolean "drawing" is true, then I turn off all event handling in the TextView boxes):

```
            foreach (var tv in textBoxes)
            {
                tv.Editable = !drawing;
                tv.Selectable = !drawing;

#if __IOS__
                tv.UserInteractionEnabled = !drawing;
#else
                tv.AcceptsTouchEvents = !drawing;
#endif
                foreach (var g in tv.GestureRecognizers)
                    g.Enabled = !drawing;
            }
```

So everything works perfectly between the two modes on iOS. On the Mac everything mostly work with one exception: in drawing mode (when the textview and textview gestures are disabled) if I start a gesture on top of the TextView box, nothing happens. Neither the Canvas gesture handler NOR the TextView box gesture handler are called. Starting a gesture anywhere else works fine and the Canvas gesture handler receives it.

In summary, my question is: how can I completely disable gestures in a subview, such that the superview gesture will be recognised, *even* if the gesture starts on top of the subview.

There are samples of handing a gesture to a subview, but here I want to hand a gesture to a superview (which *should* be top of the responder chain I thought).

Any advice would be gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the solution is to ensure that the subview you want to receive gestures has to be at the top, otherwise gestures dont seem to reach it (this means it has to be the last item in the Subviews array).

In other words, if another subview "A" sits above your subview "B" - and that subview "A" is completely disabled with *no* gesture recognisers... it will stop any gestures in "B" from being recognised.

Gesture recognisers are not supposed to use the responder chain... (that is made clear in UIGestureRecognizer specs, but *not* NSGestureRecognizer specs). Here is a quote from the latter:

> Events received by your app are forwarded automatically to any
> relevant gesture recognizers before they are sent to the corresponding
> view

This doesn't talk about how events flow up the responder chain for gesture recognisers on the Mac.

So as mentioned above - bring your subview to the front to ensure its gestures will be recognised. With the Mac, there is no way to easily order subviews of NSView (unlike UIView which has bringToFront, sendToBack etc). So the best way I have found is to use SortSubviews, with an appropriate ordering function.